# Installing Gtkmm on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, compiling, gcc

I heard, one should use Gtkmm when using GTK with C++ but I can't seem to get it installed. The last thing I found is [this tutorial](https://gtkmm-tutorial.blogspot.de/2016/05/how-to-install-gtkmm-on-ubuntu-1604-in-3-steps.html) which seems very straight-forward and easy. The even provide an example program and a command to compile it so I used those to make sure I don't mess up with my program or with telling CMake to use Gtkmm. However, I get this error:

```
$ g++ GtkmmTutorial.cpp -o GtkmmTutorial `pkg-c
onfig gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs`
In file included from /usr/include/gdkmm-3.0/gdkmm/dragcontext.h:30:0,
                 from /usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm.h:90,
                 from GtkmmTutorial.cpp:1:
/usr/include/gdkmm-3.0/gdkmm/color.h:36:21: fatal error: gdk/gdk.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

The same error occurs when I use `gcc` instead of `g++`:

```
$ gcc GtkmmTutorial.cpp -o GtkmmTutorial `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs`
In file included from /usr/include/gdkmm-3.0/gdkmm/dragcontext.h:30:0,
                 from /usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm.h:90,
                 from GtkmmTutorial.cpp:1:
/usr/include/gdkmm-3.0/gdkmm/color.h:36:21: fatal error: gdk/gdk.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: AFAIK `/usr/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdk.h` belongs to package `libgtk-3-dev` which should have been installed as a dependency of `libgtkmm-3.0-dev` but check that it was; if necessary re-install it. Also check that `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags` includes a `-I/usr/include/gtk-3.0` directive.

Comment: The package was already installed and I reinstalled it. The command prints [this](http://pastebin.com/XKjyUsNc) which contains a similar string but not that exact string. Are you sure it's not `-I/usr/local/include/gtk-3.0`?

Comment: AFAIK packages from the repository *never* install in /usr/local - most likely you have installed gtkmm-3.0 from another source at some point and `pkg-config` is finding the local `.pc` file ahead of that provided by the system package

Comment: I installed something related to GTK a week ago via `make` and `make install` to start writing a program that uses GTK. Merely installing it changed how for example Firefox looked a few minutes after the installation and when I tried to reboot, Ubuntu wouldn't boot any more. I wasn't even able to get into a TTY.  But I managed to rescue the system and in the process of doing so uninstalled the installation I made via `make install`. `/usr/local/include` contains the folders `gail-3.0` and `gtk-3.0`. Both contain subfolders but not a single file (I checked all the subfolders).

Comment: Does `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig` still contain any gtk/gdk related .pc files though?

Comment: @steeldriver Yes. It contains 6 files totaling 2.6 kB with names like `gail-3.0.pc` or `gtk+-x11-3.0.pc`. Doesn't contain any folders.

Comment: `pkg-config` will search /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig ahead of /usr/lib/pkgconfig, and so will return the wrong `--cflags` and `--libs` values (i.e. those for the - now deleted - local install of the corresponding libraries).

Comment: So should I delete that folder?

Comment: If you don't have any software in /usr/local, then yes - or rename it something like `old-pkgconfig` just in case

Comment: Thank you! It works now. Want to post this as an answer?